# How do I know if a regexp has more than one possible match?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing Java code that has to distinguish regular expressions with more than one possible match from regular expressions that have only one possible match.

For example:

"abc." can have several matches ("abc1", abcf", ...), 
while "abcd" can only match "abcd".

Right now my best idea was to look for all unescaped regexp special characters.

I am convinced that there is a better way to do it in Java. Ideas?

(Late addition):

To make things clearer - there is NO specific input to test against. A good solution for this problem will have to test the regex itself.

In other words, I need a method who'se signature may look something like this:

```
boolean isSingleResult(String regex)
```

This method should return true if only for **one** possible String s1. The expression s1.matches(regex) will return true. (See examples above.)

Comment: Note that there are regex-patterns that have meta characters, but can only match a single string. For example, the regex `abc(?=d).` can only match the string `abcd`.

Comment: Or `(abc|abc)`, `[a][b][c]` and other theoretically possible/practically useless constructs. But probably the biggest problem is lookaround, as Bart noted. So if you have a regex without any special characters, you can be sure that it has only one match - but you can't say that a regex with special character will have zero, one or more possible matches. Consider also regexes that by definition never match, like `$x`...

Comment: thanks. I'm no regex expert (otherwise I'd extend the Pattern class to support this feature naturally) but I assumed there will be cases where a singule-result regex can be built using special characters. however, as I mentioned this is the best idea I have got so far...

Comment: I don't know of a 3rd party library that does exactly that. I also think it will be pretty darn difficult to write such a tool. At least a tool that accounts for the non-trivial regex-es with *look-arounds* etc.

Comment: Can we ask why you need this?  Maybe there's a more outside-the-box approach to the meta-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds dirty, but it might be worth having a look at the [Pattern class in the Java source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.html).

Taking a quick peek, it seems like it 'normalize()'s the given regex (Line 1441), which could turn the expression into something a little more predictable. I think reflection can be used to tap into some private resources of the class (use caution!). It could be possible that while tokenizing the regex pattern, there are specific indications if it has reached some kind "multi-matching" element in the pattern.

**Update**

After having a closer look, there is some data within package scope that you can use to leverage the work of the Pattern tokenizer to walk through the nodes of the regex and check for multiple-character nodes.

After compiling the regular expression, iterate through the compiled "Node"s starting at Pattern.root. Starting at line 3034 of the class, there are the generalized types of nodes. For example class Pattern.All is multi-matching, while Pattern.SingleI or Pattern.SliceI are single-matching, and so on.

All these token classes appear to be in package scope, so it should be possible to do this without using reflection, but instead creating a java.util.regex.PatternHelper class to do the work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done this sort of hacking so my info may be out of date, but I believe the default Java classloader stack restricts who can load java.* classes.  I'm just saying it may also require a custom classloader.  I still think it's probably the best solution short of creating your own regex parser.

Comment: thanks. boss decided we should simply mark the "non-regexp" string with a prefix, so it seems I won't dive into the Pattern class yet, but from all the answers I got your solution would probably be the way I'd go at it if I had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If it can only have one possible match it isn't *reeeeeally* an expression, now, is it? I suspect your best option is to use a different tool altogether, because this does not at all sound like a job for regular expressions, but if you insist, well, no, I'd say your best option is to look for unescaped special characters.

Comment: The problem is that even non-generic expressions are *really* expressions - otherwise my job would be as easy as try-catch-ing Pattern.compile()...

Comment: using a try/catch-block for validating input where an exception is expected is also not a good design. but nevermind that, all i'm saying is that if you only want to deal with patterns entirely without special characters, then you are most likely trying to do something that is not best achieved with regular expressions after all. it is hard to say what your best solution would be, without knowing what it is you're trying to do in further detail, but something involving String.Contains, perhaps?

Comment: I agree that I am in a somewhat sad situation. my task is very specific and well-defined, and it is to extend some existing filtering mechanism to use regex. The existing mechanism distinguishes between general(String.startsWith) and exact patterns by means of a prefix. my job is to use regex to extend searching capabilities and loose the all-annoying prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The only regular expression that can ONLY match one input string is one that specifies the string exactly. So you need to match expressions with no wildcard characters or character groups AND that specify a start "^" and end "$" anchor.

- "the quick" matches:

  - "the quick brownfox"
  - "the quick brown dog"
  - "catch the quick brown fox"
- "^the quick brown fox$" matches ONLY:

  - "the quick brown fox"

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you mean. I live in Belgium...

So this is something what work on most expressions. I wrote this by myself. So maybe I forgot some rules.

```
public static final boolean isSingleResult(String regexp) {
    // Check the exceptions on the exceptions.
    String[] exconexc = "\\d \\D \\w \\W \\s \\S".split(" ");
    for (String s : exconexc) {
        int index = regexp.indexOf(s);
        if (index != -1) // Forbidden char found
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Then remove all exceptions:
    String regex = regexp.replaceAll("\\\\.", "");
    // Now, all the strings how can mean more than one match
    String[] mtom = "+ . ? | * { [:alnum:] [:word:] [:alpha:] [:blank:] [:cntrl:] [:digit:] [:graph:] [:lower:] [:print:] [:punct:] [:space:] [:upper:] [:xdigit:]".split(" ");
    // iterate all mtom-Strings
    for (String s : mtom) {
        int index = regex.indexOf(s);
        if (index != -1) // Forbidden char found
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Martijn

Answer (score -2):

I see that the only way is to check if regexp matches multiple times for particular input.

```
package com;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class AAA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "123 321 443 52134 432";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            ++i;
        }
        System.out.printf("Matched %d times%n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understood the OP. There is *no* input. There is only the regex.

Comment: besides ignoring the question's problematic aspect (the need to match an infinite number of inputs), it is also not a real answer to the question...